# How to fix Javascript code with error on split() undefined and onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, split, undefined, e-commerce

My background: I learned CSS & HTML a few years ago and I am learning Javascript & JQuery. Currently, I've got to improve the e-commerce website of my company.

Here's what I am trying to do.

I've got a product page where there is a picture of a product (inside a window) and some colour buttons.

When you click on a colour button, it gets selected but the photo doesn't change.

You probably guessed it, **I want to add code that shows the picture** of the product **when you click/select the colour** that matches it.

I wrote a JS code and my idea behind it, is to isolate the url of the picture and to change it by the one corresponding to the colour.

The problem is that I get this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.**

I searched for solutions but none of them seem to correspond to my problem. Thus, I need help.

Here's the HTML (the window/block showing the picture of the product):

```
<div 
    style="z-index: 999;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; 
    background-position: -144px 0px;
    width: 456px; height: 343px;
    float: left; 
    cursor: crosshair;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; 
    background-image: url(&quot;https://be-goji.com/wp-
    content/uploads/2017/01/OSSO-ROSE.jpg&quot;);
    top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;"
    class="zoomWindow">&nbsp;
</div>
```

Here's a snippet of a Javascript code that I wrote in order to fix it (with comments):

```
// isolates the HTML from the window
var colorSwitch = document.getElementsByClassName('zoomWindow'); 

// splits the code in several strings in an array
var colorSwitchUrl = colorSwitch[0].split(';') 

// extracts the string I want to change
var colorSwitchChange = colorSwitchUrl.slice(12,13);

// gets the element I want to put the event onto
var chooseColorNoir = document.getElementsByTagName('label'); 

//function that brings picture to show in the window on click
chooseColorNoir[0].onclick = function(){ 

   // makes the string disappear
   colorSwitchChange.pop();

   // replaces it with a good one
   colorSwitchChange.push("https://be-goji.com/wp-
   content/uploads/2017/01/coco_noir.jpg"); 
};
```

Could you help me find where the problem lies? Do you have another method that you recommend?

Thanks a million!

Nat

Note: I have got to call the picture with an url since it isn't available on the page.

Comment: please try to add your js with script tag inside the bottom of body tag,

Comment: This `colorSwitch[0]` is returning nothing.  At the time that code runs it can't find any elements with the class name zoomWindow.  Is the zoomWindow something that appears and disappears?

Comment: Can you give us a link to the site?

Comment: `colorSwitch[0]` return `HTMLDivElement`. You cannot run `split()` on that element, because it's not a string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you want to do this much. If I understood your question Properly, you want to change the image based on user selection. You can simply do that like this.

I added two labels and gave those a unique color attribute and on click I am checking for that attribute value and accordingly changing the background image of the product div. No need to do any kind of string manipulations.

**HTML:**

```
<div 
    style="z-index: 999;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; 
    background-position: -144px 0px;
    width: 456px; height: 343px;
    float: left; 
    cursor: crosshair;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; 
    background-image: url('https://be-goji.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/OSSO-ROSE.jpg');
    top: 0px; left: 0px;"
    class="zoomWindow">&nbsp;
</div>

<div style="float:right">
  <label itemColor="Rose">Rose</label> <label itemColor="Coco">Coco</label>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
// isolates the HTML from the window
var colorSwitch = document.getElementsByClassName('zoomWindow')[0]; 


//function that brings picture to show in the window on click
var myFunction = function(){ 
  if(this.getAttribute("itemColor") == "Rose"){
    colorSwitch.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://be-goji.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/OSSO-ROSE.jpg')";
  }
  else if(this.getAttribute("itemColor") == "Coco"){
      colorSwitch.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://be-goji.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/coco_noir.jpg')";
  }
};

// gets the element I want to put the event onto
var chooseColorNoir = document.getElementsByTagName('label'); 
for (var i = 0; i < chooseColorNoir.length; i++) {
    chooseColorNoir[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

[Working Pen for your reference](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYGZqe?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This fixes it.
Now the challenge is to integrate it to the page but don't worry I'll ask around if I've got issues.